# Disable system font size effect in my app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I don't want the system font size have any effect in my app. If I increase system font size in Android settings, the text in my app will be unreadable (i.e. too big).

How can I solve it?

I'm writing my code in C#, Xamarin.Forms project.

Comment: Did you tried to add the `FontSize` attribute to the desired control?

Comment: Yeah i did..... :)

Comment: there is no accepted answer but it may could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43290757/prevent-system-fontsize-change-from-affecting-the-size-in-the-xamarin-applicatio

Comment: I already did it but unfortunately nothing changed. :(

Comment: Don't use `sp` then.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Disable system font size effect in my App

If you need set a fixed text size for your application, you try using the following code to implement this feature:

```
private void initFontScale()
{
     Configuration configuration = Resources.Configuration;
     configuration.FontScale = (float)1.45;
     //0.85 small, 1 standard, 1.15 big，1.3 more bigger ，1.45 supper big 
     DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
     WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(metrics);
     metrics.ScaledDensity = configuration.FontScale * metrics.Density;
     BaseContext.Resources.UpdateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);
}

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    initFontScale();
    ...
}
```

Comment: to avoid the use of the Obsolete method UpdateConfiguration, use this:  
            BaseContext.ApplicationContext.CreateConfigurationContext(configuration);
            BaseContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics.SetTo(metrics);

Comment: This only works with the non depreciated methods as stated in the comment!

Comment: This works with Api 31, but not anymore with Api 32.

Answer (score 1):

code works but it dont't work with horizontal page

```
private void initFontScale()
{
     Configuration configuration = Resources.Configuration;
     configuration.FontScale = (float)1.45;
     //0.85 small, 1 standard, 1.15 big，1.3 more bigger ，1.45 supper big 
     DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
     WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(metrics);
     metrics.ScaledDensity = configuration.FontScale * metrics.Density;
     BaseContext.Resources.UpdateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);
}

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    initFontScale();
    ...
}
```