# Xamarin.forms - font size depending on phone settings

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have some problem with font. I have created UI and it looks as expected when phone has setted default font size and default display size. When font size and display size are setted to largest my UI is crashing. I'm using FontSize from 10 to 22.

Can you tell me what is the best approach to create UI, which will work correctly no matter on display size and font size?

Comment: May be you need approach like this: `var sz = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label))`?

Comment: Is any way to block font size in application, when user increases it in phone settings?

Comment: I found solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50289763/disable-system-font-size-effect-in-my-app-c-sharp-xamarin-forms-android/50322223#50322223