# Xamarin Form Accessibility scaling for Named Font Size

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have an app in android creating using Xamarin.Forms which looks as required when accessibility "Font Size" & "Display Size" setting is set to "Default". I am using NamedSize.Small and NamedSize.Medium in most places.

But when I change both of them to maximum possible value then size of labels are getting increased by 3-4 times. And also font size get increase if I changed Font Size or display size. So I would like to know whether there is any option where I can manage the ratio I want to change when "Font Size" & "Default Size" is changed. And whether there is any properties which suggest which of the two is changed and how much. Or may be disable "Default Size" changes and only allow "Font Size" to work.

I know there is `Density` & `ScaledDensity` in DisplayMetrics class. But can't find how it work and how to use those properties.

Same applies to iOS when accessibility setting in that. So far I have only found that there is a property `EnableAccessibilityScalingForNamedFontSizes` to disable accessibility scaling for named font sizes

Comment: ,According to your description, I don't know what do you want to do, but If you want to disable accessibility font scaling when you have set fontsize for control, you can use custom render to do this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43290757/prevent-system-fontsize-change-from-affecting-the-size-in-the-xamarin-applicatio

Comment: No, I don't want to disable Font Scaling. I want to disable or limit "Display Size" i.e. Density.

Comment: For Font Scaling I am already updating configuration using CreateConfigurationContext. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.content.context.createconfigurationcontext?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9

Comment: can you post some code or screenshot here? It helps me to understand your question better.