# Xamarin Forms: When the Text and Display are Set to Large, So Does Everything Else

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having a problem on xamarin ios and android. 
if the device has set the text and display size to large, all the sizes in my app become enlarged. 
how can I set the default size when opening the app?

Comment: Can we see what youre currently trying?

Comment: nothing, I have no idea where to put or disable the system configuration of the text or display size. =(

Comment: Looks like you will need to write a renderer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43290757/prevent-system-fontsize-change-from-affecting-the-size-in-the-xamarin-applicatio

Comment: this solution is obsolete, only affects Android. I still have the problem on IOS. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: In iOS, the text size won't be affect by system font size if you give a fixed size to label like: `<Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" FontSize="35"/>`. Can you please add a Minimal, Reproducible Example here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add following code in main activity android

```
//For android
        #region Reset Fonts to default
        /// <summary>
        /// Reset fonts.
        /// </summary>
        public override Resources Resources
        {
            get
            {
                Resources res = base.Resources;
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                config.SetToDefaults();
                res.UpdateConfiguration(config, res.DisplayMetrics);
                return res;
            }

        }
        #endregion
```

//