# Android WebView bad rendering of CSS linear background with text overlay

Tags: android, css, xamarin, webview, rendering

I'm working on Xamarin Forms targeting Android 13 and since 2 weeks I'm fighting against an annoying rendering problem on a WebView which as far as I understood (by Googling 24/7) is based on the basic Android HTML Viewer which is based on Chromium / WebKit.

After reading a huge amount of threads about the topic and trying every possible solution and suggestion, I'm here asking for help.

---

**The Problem**

I have a quite simple HTML/CSS page to be shown on a WebView.

The page has an alternate color striped background achieved using a CSS linear-gradient and I need the text to be correctly aligned in the stripes.

I used `background-size` and `line-height` with `em` units in order to keep a good ratio between Font size, line height and background (stripe) height.
I've seen that the background-size must be double the line-height and of course they have to be a multiple of the font-size.

Rule of thumb:

- line-height (adimensional): 4
- (or) line-height (in px): 4 * font-size
- background-size (in px or em): 2 * line-height

I need each line of text to be contained in the stripe for any font size, so if I change the font size, I need that when the word wrap they fall into the next colored stripe.

---

**Desired outcome/Real outcome**

Image link:
[Left: good rendering in any browser; Center: good rendering with good word wrap on any browser; Right: outcome on my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rccsh.png)

The page renders just fine:

- on any PC browser
- on my App's WebView on the Android Emulator (both "Pixel5 API 29" and "Pixel5 API 33")
- on Google Chrome on my Android phone which is a Samsung Galaxy XPro 6.

It does not render correctly:

- on my App's WebView on my Samsung Galaxy XPro 6 phone

---

**The Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Space Story</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Verdana', sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .striped-bg {
            background: linear-gradient(0deg, grey 50%, white 50%);
            background-size: 100% 8em !important;
            line-height: 4 !important;
            padding: 0px 18px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="striped-bg"><p>In the year 2050, humanity had reached a new milestone in space exploration. 
    The first manned mission to Mars had been successfully completed, and the world was abuzz with excitement about the possibilities that lay ahead. 
    As part of the ongoing efforts to expand humanity's presence in the cosmos, a team of six astronauts was selected to embark on a long-term mission to a distant planet in the Alpha Centauri system.
    <br><br>...<br></p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Reproducible Example Repository**

I'm putting this here so anyone wanting to help can clone it and try to reproduce the problem on their own phone.

https://github.com/NitroHxC/AndroidWebViewBadRendering

It's based on the base Xamarin Forms template, with additions in `AboutPage.xaml` and `AboutPage.xaml.cs`

---

**What I tried (unsuccessfully)**

I'm using Xamarin Forms 5.0.0.2578 and Xamarin Essentials 1.7.5 .

I'm using the Plugin.HybridWebView by Ryan Dixon but I've tried also the base Xamarin WebView and also the SuperWebView plugin by Axemasta, all with the same outcome.

I tried putting CSS resets and the `max-height` as suggested in many threads in order to disable font boosting, without success.

```
 * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    html * {
        max-height: 1000000px;
    }
```

I tried putting the meta viewport without success:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

---

**Other hints and data**

I tried printing out my User Agent data using a javascript injection in the WebView and I got this results:

Emulator User Agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 13; sdk_gphone64_x86_64 Build/TPB3.220513.017;wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/101.0.4951.74 Mobile Safari 537.36
```

Phone User Agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 13; SM-G736B Build/TP1A.220624.014; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/111.0.5563.116 Mobile Safari 537.36
```

This makes me think it's not Version issue, because the Chrome version seems newer on the phone ... but I have no idea what it could be.

Another thing I did was trying to "compensate" for the background misalignment by replacing the `background-size: 8em` with the actual `px` value and slowly tweaking it until it looked good on the phone, and in the end I found that the `background-size` should be exactly 2.2 times the `line-height` in order to get the desired outcome on my phone (instead of 2 times on any other browser).

So for instance for a `font-size:14px`, these are the values that work on my phone:

```
.striped-bg {
            background: linear-gradient(0deg, grey 50%, white 50%);
            background-size: 100% 123.2px !important;
            line-height: 56px !important;
            padding: 0px 18px;
        }
```

But what happened next? I sent my app to a friend and when he opened it on his phone it was messed up ! So at the moment I can't find a solution that works for everyone and I'm a bit frustrated.

And I can't even understand if it's just the `background-size` that comes out "stretched", or if it's the dreaded problem of the font boosting.

I'm thinking about trying to use a different engine for the Webview, I found there is a Xamarin.Android.GeckoView but I get all sorts of version mismatch errors with the NuGet packages when I try to use it and I'm not sure if I should take this painful path, maybe there is a simpler solution?

Again, for anyone wishing to help, here's a reproducible example:

https://github.com/NitroHxC/AndroidWebViewBadRendering

---

Any other idea is deeply appreciated! Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Reasonably certain that it is independent of Chrome version. Its been years since I did anything similar, but I can make some observations that might help. I observe that it is **slightly** off; whatever the problem is, it is accumulating over the screen. First, Does the phone have a "Density" that is NOT an Integer?  E.g. `2.75` rather than `3`? If so, make an emulator with the same Density. Does the problem occur there? Second, can you test on a phone that is NOT by Samsung? If it only fails on Samsung, then it seems likely to be related to fonts.

Comment: Third, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50322223/199364. Yes, that is a deprecated method, but it may be more effective than the not-deprecated https://stackoverflow.com/a/74369314/199364. HOWEVER, that is primarily for Xamarin.Forms fonts; it might not help WebView rendering.

Comment: Fourth, especially if only happens on Samsung devices, make sure test device has ALL forms of "zoom" manually set to defaults. [Worst case, do Factory Reset.] While this won't help for users that have non-default settings, it may help isolate the source of the problem. Annoyingly, Samsung has made it non-obvious what the "default" settings are. E.g. "Screen Zoom" starts one "tick" away from left IIRC. Find a solution that works with default settings, then vary the settings to see what breaks it.

Comment: Might be easier to stop putting gradient on the background. **Can you rewrite the HTML so that each line is a box containing its gradient and the text?**